# Angular forms add input field on click

Tags: angular

I want to add new input field on click but to select the text on the previous input field so that it will be edited.

[First view of fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOglV.png)

[Second view of fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVCnk.png)

When I click on field (Add Workstation) I want to select the previous field with (Unnamed workstation) and the Add workstation to be always visible and below. I have been trying to find a way to achieve this but with no luck until now.

html:

```
<div class="_form-item" *ngIf="item.type=='station'&& item.id" style="padding-top: 32px">
  <div class="_label">Work Stations</div>
  <div class="_ml-12 _pt-8 _flex-row" *ngFor="let work_station of item.children; let i = index;
                trackBy: customTrackBy">
    <input [id]="i" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkStation(i)"
           [(ngModel)]="item.children[i].name"
           type="text"/>
    <div class="_icon-button" (click)="removeWorkStation(i)"><i
      class="material-icons md-dark md-18">clear</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="_ml-12 _pt-8 _flex-row">
    <input (click)="createWorkStation()" placeholder="Add work station" [(ngModel)]="newWorkStation"
           type="text"/>
    <!--div class="_link-button">Add</div-->
  </div>
</div>
```

component function:

```
createWorkStation() {
    let item = new Location();
    item.type = 'work_station';
    item.name = 'Unnamed work station ';
    item.parent = this.item.group_id;
    this.service.create(item)
    .map((response: Response) => <Location>response.json())
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.onCreateChild.emit({id: data.id});
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you're not able to add it, please add a starting point in code.

Comment: I do not understand at all your question. So you want a second input field under the first one if you click on 'Add work station'? If so, you can just add a new Entity in the list `item.children` you display in `createWorkStation`. The View will update itself.

Comment: @kedenk When I click Add work station field I want this field to move down and add a new field above it with a default value but the value selected and ready to be edited. The problem is when I click the Add work station field I cannot automatically focus and select the above newly added field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to every `input` field a template variable (`#test`):

```
<input #test [id]="i" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkStation(i)"
       [(ngModel)]="item.children[i].name"
       type="text"/>
```

With this template variable, you can use `ViewChildren` and its `change` Observable to track if a new `input` field is added to the view:

```
@ViewChildren('test') el: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

However, subscribing to the `change` Observable must be done in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.el.changes.subscribe( next => {
          setTimeout(() => this.elementFocus());
      });
  }

  elementFocus() {
      if( this.el != undefined && this.el.last != undefined ) {
          this.el.last.nativeElement.focus();
          this.el.last.nativeElement.select();
     }
  }
```

Here is a [working example](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-td4v69) for you